# Subgroup of $S_8$ isomorphic to $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me to prove the following result:

I recall that the holomorph $Hol(\Gamma)$ of a group $\Gamma$ is the semidirect product $Hol(\Gamma)=\Gamma\ltimes_{\phi} Aut(\Gamma)$ where $\phi: Aut(\Gamma)\to  Aut(\Gamma)$ is the identity map.

Let $G=Hol(C_8)$. In addition let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $8$, $L$ a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and suppose that $Gal(L/\mathbb{Q})\cong G$

> Show that there is a subgroup of $S_8$ isomorphic to $G$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused by your question; it seems like it is completely independent of your preamble about the holomorph of a group. If $L/K$ is the splitting field of an irreducible polynomial $f(X) \in K[X]$ of degree $n$, and $L/K$ is Galois with Galois group $G$, then $G$ always embeds into $S_{n}$: the action of $G$ on the roots of $f$ furnish a homomorphism $G \to S_{n}$, and since the roots of $f$ generate $L$ over $K$, an element of $g$ fixes every root of $f$ if and only if it is the identity on $L$.

Comment: Incidentally, if $\Gamma$ is a group of order $n$, then $Hol(\Gamma)$ embeds into $S_{n}$ via an argument similar to that usually given to prove Cayley's theorem. If this is what you're really asking, you might want to make that clear.

Comment: can you please write this clearly as an answer, and use the same notation as the post since I am a little bit confused. Thanks in advance

Comment: @siwar can you please show some evidence that you have tried to answer this question yourself?