# Conjugation in $S_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am reviewing for a test and i find the following good exercice. Would you please help me to prove the second part of the question b) here [image]

for question a) i find $|G|=32$ since $G=C_8\ltimes C_2\times C_2$
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What book is that exercise from?

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. You could at least provide your answer to (a).

Comment: @ DonAntonio , I took it from a friend to review for the test he didn't give me the source of the exercice. @ Ethan Bolker, for a) i find $|G|=32$ since $G=C_8 \ltimes_{\phi} C_2\times  C_2$

Comment: This user seemed to ask almost the same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2639383/subgroup-of-s-8-isomorphic-to-g